# How to force run an application in the background at startup

Tags: boot, windows-11, task-manager, background

I have an application (a keyboard driver) which launches at startup without issues. It's basically a keyboard configuration utility, which sets up macros, keyboard lights, remaps, etc. Problem is, it runs in the foreground and all up in my face. If you exit the GUI, it sits at system tray and behaves there. I want to force Windows not to display its GUI on startup and make it sit in system tray as I don't need to always modify it.

It's a Langtu LT104 keyboard and while I love it, the GUI has no options to do this.

If there's a way to do this via the Task Manager (it's already in the list of apps in the Startup tab there), or via a bat file at startup, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make a link to to the executable and set the link to open *Minimized*. Runt eh .lnk file at startup, rather than the executable directly.

For example, I've a batch file to run Firefox single-instance, and don't want to see the CMD prompt on screen:

[image: Minimze on Run]